# Why was Ignite 2.7.0 removed from the distribution folder?

Tags: ignite

Our deployment automation pulls Ignite from http://www.us.apache.org/dist/ignite/2.7.0/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip which is now an empty folder. Does it have a permanent home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because 2.7.5 is now released. I guess this location only contains the last version. You can still download it from https://archive.apache.org/dist/ignite/2.7.0/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip